# Algorithm for a matter of chance game

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, complexity-theory

I started developing an algorithm for a matter of chance game with the following rules:

- At the start of the game, the player starts on the starting case S(Start).
- He starts by rolling the dice and advances the number of spaces indicated on it.
- Possible Values of the dice goes from 1 to 6.
- Then the player executes the action indicated on the current case (advance, go back, relance the dice(if the current case is R: Relance)).
- Each action costs 1 turn.
- The game is won when the player reaches the finish case E(End). The player must fall exactly on the finish line and can not exceed it.
- The starting and ending cases S and E are not necessarily at the beginning and at the end of the tray.
- A turn coming out of the board loses the game.

Here is an example:

| 4 | **S** | -2 | 1 | **R** | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | -5 | 2 | -4 | **E** |

The player starts on the S case. The fastest way to win is:

- Roll the dice and make a 3, to get to the R square (turn 1).
- Re-roll the dice and make a 6, to get to square 2 (turn 2).
- The player is obliged to advance by 2 cases and arrives in the case E (turn 3).

The expected result is 3, because it takes 3 launches at least to finish the game.

My solution is based on an algorithm that starts from the End case and checks what cases drive to the End one. Then, I will check which cases can reach to the cases that I already found. That way, I will not have to check the cases that does not lead to the end case.

The thing is , I prefer to give more importance to the quality of the code and its effectiveness because I think that the algorithm that I found is not enough.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can see your board as a directed graph. Each case is a node, numbered cases have edges connecting them to the case they point you to, while S and R cases have six edges connecting them to the next six cases. Edges have all the same weight.

In this case your problems becomes finding the distance between starting and ending nodes along the shortest path, a problem which [has been widely studied in many different variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

For reference, you could look a standard [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), your algorithm should be something equivalent to this one (You can return as soon as you find your destination though, the complete algorithm calculates the distances from a node to ALL other nodes).

I don't think that the decision of whether to star from the End case or from the Start one is important, in both cases you will have some board structures that will be slower or faster to analyze, but the average complexity should be the same. (As you said, starting from End you avoid checking cases that do not lead to it, but starting from Start you would avoid checking cases that are not reachable from it)